# Group by and sum the previous element

Tags: python, pandas

Good Morning, I have the following df:

```
print(df)

Date          cod_id      Sales    Initial_stock  
01/01/2017      1           5          5                
01/01/2017      2           4          8                
02/01/2017      1           1          5                 
...
```

Since there are a few mistakes in the real dataset, regarding "Initial_stock", I would like to create a new column, for the different *cod_id*s(= products), as:

Initial stock in the previous row of that *cod_id* + current value of initial stock - Sales;  so:

```
print(df_final)

Date          cod_id      Sales    Initial_stock  new  
01/01/2017      1           5          5           0          
01/01/2017      2           4          8           4                      
02/01/2017      1           1          5           4  
...
```

In which the last value equals to 4 of *"cod_id 1"* is computed as: 0 + 5 - 1 = 4

Comment: What is your question? Also, do you have an example of your attempts so far?

Comment: Sort by cod_id, create another column by calculating lag of initial_stock and then apply your formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

d = {'cod_id': [1, 2, 1], 'Sales': [5,4,1], 'Initial_stock': [5,8,5]}#my initil data

#######show purpose#######
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)#I print the dataframe of my initial data
print (df)
##########################

new=[]#declare a new list where I'll introduce all the new values
i=0
#I create a loop for element present in my initial list and for each subelement present I calculate the new one
while i <len(d['cod_id']):
    new_value=(d['Initial_stock'][i])-(d['Sales'][i])#clculation new=initial_stock-sales
    new.append(new_value)#append my new value in the new list
    i+=1

#######show purpose#######
print (new)#print my new list to show that the calculation is correct
##########################

d['new']=new#add my new data to the original list

#######show purpose#######
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)#create the data frame with my new values and print it again
print (df)
##########################
```